# change fringe face height

Tags: faces, fringe

This increases the buffer text height:

```lisp
(face-remap-add-relative 'default :height 1.5)
```

This has no effect on the fringe continuation mark heights:

```lisp
(face-remap-add-relative 'fringe :height 1.5)
```

So how can I change the height of glyphs in the fringe?

Comment: The fringe displays bitmaps, not glyphs, so the `fringe` face is only used to set the default background colour

Comment: The O.P. may wish to define a new bitmap that is taller:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Customizing-Bitmaps.html  Here is an example where I set the height to 12 pixels:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/12240/2287